# How can I default to the alphabet keypad on focus of an EditText view?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

My scenario:

I have 2 EditText:

```
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edt1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
   android:inputType="textPassword"
   android:maxLength="8"                               
   android:singleLine="true" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/add"/>
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edt2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:digits="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
   android:inputType="textPassword"
   android:maxLength="8"                               
   android:singleLine="true" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/edt1"/>
```

When edt1 is focused, I input number(keyboard shows number) then I next edt2, keyboard still displays number.

I want to keyboard change number to qwerty keyboard.

How can I do this?

UPDATED: I mean: qwerty keyboard always show when EditText is focused.

Thanks all!

Comment: remove `android:digits` from both.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But just allow those characters.

Comment: what should I do when edittext has focus?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:digits` from both. In first EditText use `android:inputType="number"` and in second one use `android:inputType="text"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<EditText 
 android:id="@+id/edt1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"      
   android:inputType="number"
   android:maxLength="8"                               
   android:singleLine="true" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/add"/>
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edt2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"       
   android:inputType="text"
   android:maxLength="8"                               
   android:singleLine="true" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/edt1"/>
```